# jQuery timepicker forces a value

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am using [Trent Richardson's Timepicker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I have a form that has optional timepicker fields.  When the form is loaded, default values for these fields are being set.

Does anyone know how to set the default value of timepicker fields to blank?

**HTML being generated:**

```
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="birthday"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_datetime" name="birthday" value="01/01/1970 01:00 AM"/><label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
</p><div class="item_header">
    <label>Office Hours</label>
</div>
<p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="start_office"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_time" name="start_office" value="01:00 AM"/><label for="start_office">Start of the day</label>
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="end_office"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_time" name="end_office" value="01:00 AM"/><label for="end_office">Gone for the day</label>
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="vacation_start"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_date" name="vacation_start" value="01/01/1970"/><label for="vacation_start">Vacation start</label>
</p><p class="name">
```

**JS:**

```
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({ampm: true,hourGrid: 4,minuteGrid: 15, timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'});
        $('.form_date').datepicker();
        $('.form_time').timepicker({ampm: true, hourGrid: 4,minuteGrid: 15, timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'});
//attempt to clear out html data being generated by plugin
$('.datetime_value_fix').each(function(){ 
  field_name = $(this).attr('id'); 
  field_value = $(this).val(); 
  $(' :input').each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).attr('name') == field_name){ 
      if ($(this).val() != field_value){ 
        $(this).val(field_value); 
      } 
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the `value` from inputs :

```
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="birthday"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_datetime" name="birthday" value=""/><label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
</p><div class="item_header">
    <label>Office Hours</label>
</div>
<p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="start_office"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_time" name="start_office" value=""/><label for="start_office">Start of the day</label>
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="end_office"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_time" name="end_office" value=""/><label for="end_office">Gone for the day</label>
</p><p class="name">
    <input type="hidden" class="datetime_value_fix" value="" id="vacation_start"/>
    <input type="text" class="form_date" name="vacation_start" value=""/><label for="vacation_start">Vacation start</label>
</p><p class="name">
```

Comment: I have tried doing that with the following JS code:
$('.datetime_value_fix').each(function(){
       field_name = $(this).attr('id');
       field_value = $(this).val();
       $(' :input').each(function(){
           if ($(this).attr('name') == field_name){
               if ($(this).val() != field_value){
                   $(this).val(field_value);
               }
           }
       });

This does not appear to clear the value.  I have placed alerts to see that it is trying to clear the default values with the those of their respective hidden fields but the HTML still keeps the defaullts

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the plugin to not put the default values in the HTML.  I was hoping there was an option in the timepicker plugin but have not found any.  timepicker-addon.js property "alwaysSetTime" looked promising but it does not appear to do what I want.